# Dynamic memory allocation from the heap

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, heap-memory

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int a,n;
    int * ptr_data;


    printf ("Enter amount: ");
    scanf ("%d",&a);
    int arr[a];
    ptr_data = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) );
    for ( n=0; n<a; n++ )
    {
        printf ("Enter number #%d: ",n);
        scanf ("%d",&ptr_data[n]);
    }

    for ( n=0; n<a; n++ )
        arr[n] = ptr_data[n]; //values in heap are copied to an array.
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(ptr_data));
    free (ptr_data);
    printf ("Output: ");
    for ( n=0; n<a; n++ )
        printf("%d\n",arr[n]);
    return 0;
}
```

the sizeof function prints the size of pointer as 4(integer's size). but i run a loop to get the values to be stored in the heap (scanf,.), so how does this subsequent pointee pointer mapping happens after first time? as in, first time i explicitly code that the ptr_data to contain a size of 4. but after that when i want to store another integer this pointer shows another random memory refernce(this mapping explanation is what all i want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your code is an **Undefined behavior**.

```
 ptr_data = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) );
```

Allocates memory equivalent to size of a single integer on heap and `ptr_data` points to this allocated memory. Further,

```
for ( n=0; n<a; n++ )
{
    printf ("Enter number #%d: ",n);
    scanf ("%d",&ptr_data[n]);
}
```

Writes beyond the bounds of the allocate memory:

```
ptr_data[n];
```

is equivalent to:

```
*(ptr_data + n);
```

Note that writing beyond the bounds of memory which belongs to you results in Undefined behavior in C and C++ both. With undefined behavior the program doesn't need to behave in any specific way.It many work correctly or crash or show any random behavior, simple the behavior is undefined.

Comment: but its working. so you say that the compiler allocates the memory automatically? This is one beautiful explanation btw! Thanks!

Comment: @bks4line: A [good read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).It is important to understand these concepts if you are working on C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

The line `ptr_data = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) )` allocates memory for only one integer pointer. You're trying to assign more than one value into `ptr_data`. If you want to do this, then:

```
ptr_data = malloc (sizeof(int) * a);
```

This will give the pointer room for `int a` integers.

Comment: You accidentally casted the return value of malloc. Don't do that.

Comment: I changed it. But why? What's the problem?

Comment: Casting has no benefits, but it can hide errors and it decreases readability.